# Laravel - Foreach loop - Show a specific message for types of result

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I have a messages table with all messages. I want pinned messages to be at top and normal ones to follow after. I have been able to do this normally with the `orderBy()` method in my query.

However, I want to display some specific messages for all my pinned messages. I would like to have a header at the top of the pinned messages and a header at the top of the normal messages to let users know that pinned and normal messages are there.

Example:

My query:

```
$rows = Messages::where('active', true)->orderBy('pinned', 'desc')->get();
```

My view

```
@foreach ($rows as $row)
    {{ $row->message }}
@endforeach
```

What I see

```
Message text 3
Message text 1
Message text 2
```

I have a few messages with "pinned" in the column in database. So I want the pinned ones to show at the top WITH DESCRIPTIONS. Something like this:

```
Pinned
----------
Message text 3
----------
Normal
----------
Message text 1
Message text 2
```

I have tried `orderBy()` and it's working pretty good, in terms of ordering it from pinned to normal, but I can't get it to show the "Pinned" and "Normal" message. How can I do this?

Comment: What about use a condition.

Comment: Can you `print_r($rows)?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (change `1/0` to `true/false` or whatever you use):

In a controller:

```
$pinned = $rows->where('pinned', 1);
$normal = $rows->where('pinned', 0);
```

In a view:

```
@if(count($pinned) > 0)
    Pinned

    @foreach ($pinned as $row)
        {{ $row->message }}
    @endforeach
@endif

@if(count($normal) > 0)
    Normal

    @foreach ($normal as $row)
        {{ $row->message }}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

If real `@foreach` part is big, use [partial and `@each`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#control-structures) instead of `@foreach` to avoid code duplication.

**Alternative**

```
@foreach ($rows as $row)
    @if ($row->pinned === 1 && !isset($pinnedShown))
        Pinned
        {{ $pinnedShown = true }}
    @endif

    @if ($row->pinned === 0 && !isset($normalShown))
        Normal
        {{ $normalShown = true }}
    @endif

    {{ $row->message }}
@endforeach
```

**Short alternative**

Not very readable, but if you just need short code, use something like this:

```
@foreach ($rows as $row)
    <?php !($row->pinned == 1 && !isset($pin)) ? : $pin = call_user_func(function(){ echo 'Pinned'; return 1; });
          !($row->pinned == 0 && !isset($nor)) ? : $nor = call_user_func(function(){ echo 'Normal'; return 1; }); ?>
    {{ $row->message }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Sorry, did not see this. I with the first way and used the `@each` blade syntax. Thank you!