# Laravel - groupBy query - grouping results in categories

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have a blog table and I have a column called `pinned` which are basically the blog posts that should be at the very top and have a header on top of all pinned blogs saying `pinned`.

For instance.

```
Pinned
----------
Pinned Blog title 1
Pinned Blog title 2
-----------
Regular
------------
Normal blog title 1
Normal blog title 2
```

How can I do this with a foreach loop and laravel groupBy query?

My query so far:

```
    $blogs = Blog::where('active', 1)->get()->groupBy('pinned');
```

That gives me two arrays of blogs; pinned and regular.

So far so good. But I don't know how to do a foreach loop with this... Please help.

I tried the following but no help..

```
 foreach ($blogs as $blog) {
        foreach ($blog as $item) {
            if($item->pinned)
                echo 'Pinned';
            echo($item->title);
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I gave you 3 alternatives here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783142/laravel-foreach-loop-show-a-specific-message-for-types-of-result

Comment: That's not how SQL grouping works. Grouping groups rows into one row, it does not somehow add additional rows to let you understand where the group starts/ends.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Wow, I did not even see that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be:

```
$blogs = Blog::where('active', 1)->groupBy('pinned')->get();
```

And the foreach loop may be like this

```
foreach ($blogs as $blog) {
    if($blog->pinned)
        echo 'Pinned';
    else echo($blog->title);
}
```